# i need to put a number and redirect to another url php

Tags: php, html, css, web

hello i dont know why when i submit a number i only get the first section here is my code i hope i get help
i want when user type 1 he redirect to a url and when user type 2 he redirect to another url

````
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class=top>
 <h2>6Virus | [ R00t ]</h2>
</div>
 <center>
 <img src="../img/anon.gif">
 <h2 style="font-size: 12px;">~# Catch Your Windows C:/ ~</h2>
 <img src="../img/app-store-2-128.png" style="margin-top: 10px;">
 <form name="form1" action="app.php" method="post">
     <input class=in type="text" name="here" placeholder="Here"/><br />
     <button class=sub type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['here']) == "1") {
 header("Location: https://instagram.com");
 exit;
}
elseif (isset($_POST['here'])  == "2") {
 header("Location: https://twitter.com");
 exit;
}
elseif (isset($_POST['here'])  == "3") {
 header("Location: https://google.com");
 exit;
}
?>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `isset` and `==` together because `isset` returns a boolean and `== 1` is truthy.

Instead, split your logic to check if `isset` and use the stirct `===` comparison instead.

## Working Example

```php
if (isset($_POST['here']) && $_POST['here'] === "1") {
 header("Location: https://instagram.com");
 exit;
}
elseif (isset($_POST['here']) && $_POST['here'] === "2") {
 header("Location: https://twitter.com");
 exit;
}
elseif (isset($_POST['here']) && $_POST['here'] === "3") {
 header("Location: https://google.com");
 exit;
}
```

### Better approach

If you want a cleaner approach, check `here` exists before hand.

```
if(isset($_POST['here'])) {
  if ($_POST['here'] === "1") {
    header("Location: https://instagram.com");
    exit;
  }
  elseif ($_POST['here'] === "2") {
    header("Location: https://twitter.com");
    exit;
  }
  elseif ($_POST['here'] === "3") {
    header("Location: https://google.com");
    exit;
  }
}
```

Example usage of `isset` and `===` [here](https://3v4l.org/O1PdA)